# Assign Variable Within Foreach Loop

Tags: php, smarty

I am fetching an array and I would like to assign attributes of items within the array to individual variables. For example, I want to assign a variable named user_1_name to include userInfo.name from the first userID and user_2_name to include userInfo.name from the second userID. Here is the code as it stands now, it uses a proprietary method named 'get_friend_list':

```
{assign var="friend_list" value=""}
{get_friend_list snid=$TOSNID snuid=$TOUID gameid=$GAMEID assign="friend_list"}
{if $friend_list|@count > 0}
  {foreach from=$friend_list key=userId item=userInfo name=friend_list}
    {if $smarty.foreach.friend_list.index < 4 && $smarty.foreach.friend_list.index >= 0 && !empty($userInfo.user_uid) }                             
      ***VARIABLE ASSIGNMENT HERE***
    {/if}
  {/foreach}
{else}
{/if}
```

If this is an unclear question, let me know and I will attempt to clear it up.

Thanks

EDIT: BTW, if you didn't notice, I am using Smarty.

Comment: please show the before and after array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
{assign var="user_{$smarty.foreach.friend_list.index}_name" value=$userInfo.name}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want? [assign](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl)